# Who is considered “respected by everyone” in regard to being Chazzan for Ne’ilah?

Tags: minhag, yom-kippur, chazzan-prayer-leader, neilah

ArtScroll (Yom Kippur Machzor, p. 708) lists several minhagim widespread during Ne’ilah, one of which is that “the rabbi, rosh yeshivah, or some member of the community whose seniority, scholarship, and piety have won him everyone’s respect serves as chazzan.”

First question: What is the original source for this minhag?

Second question: Assuming that the above quote portrays the minhag accurately, how respected is someone who has “won...everyone’s respect”? Everyone present, everyone in the community, not quite but basically everyone...?

Put another way: Let’s say that a person were chutzpadik enough to get up in front of everyone and declare that he has no respect for the person appointed as Chazzan. Would that require the Chazzan to step down and a different, well-respected person to step up, assuming that they want to follow this minhag precisely?

Comment: I think this "respected by everyone" is a constant criterion for a Shat"z for **every** service. Check O.C. on this - I don't recall exact *siman*, but it shouldn't be hard to find. What makes *ne'ilah* any different regarding this requirement?

Comment: Re - 2nd question - It means the majority of the congregation - assuming that there's no "paid" / constant *chazzan*. In the latter case, The criteria is already handled, and I think it's assumed that it was resolved prior to hiring. (I guess if enough of the congregation eventually dislikes him, they would probably fire him, anyway. though, when a "board" decides, this can be more difficult.) In short, I believe it's a **majority** preference, not a unanimous preference. Realistically, there's a curmudgeon in every group.

Comment: @DanF It’s OC 53. Generally he has to be מרוצה לעם - the chiddush by Ne’ilah is that not only is he respected, but it’s because of his “seniority, scholarship, and piety.” I would assume it’s the majority, but all it takes is one rabble-rouser... (It might not be in the board’s control - who said it’s the rabbi of the community?)

Comment: I need to view O.C. and compare the qualifications for both. BTW, in most cases, the shul board votes / hires all *klei kodesh*. B"H, they still like me ;-) (Ba'al Kri'ah).